# fubini's application

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Given $\mu$ finite Borel measure and $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$. Prove that for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}[f(x+c)-f(x)]dx= c\mu(\mathbb{R}).$$

Actually, I've tried a lot of things, one of them is trying a lemma that says
$\mu \times \mu(E)=\int \mu(E)d\mu(x)$ to get some inequality. I really don't know how to get something good in this exercise. Types?

Comment: $f(x+c)-f(x)=\mu (x,x+c]=\int \chi_{(x,x+c]} d\mu $. Integrate w.r.t. $x$ and apply  Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: I got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(y)d\mu(y)$, let $g(x,y)=\chi_{(-\infty,x+c]}(y)-\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(y)$ is measurable and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}|g(x,y)|dxd\mu(y)=c\mu(\mathbb{R})<\infty,$$
by use of Fubini's theorem we conclude that
\begin{align*}\int_{\mathbb{R}}[f(x+c)-f(x)]dx
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x,y)d\mu(y))dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x,y)dx)d\mu(y)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}cd\mu(y)=c\mu(\mathbb{R}).
\end{align*}